# Sort list of strings

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of strings like this:

```
l = ['car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG',
     'bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG',
     'car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG',
     'bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG',
     'acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG']
```

I'm trying to sort the list using the start (position 0) of each string up to the "=" character ignoring all characters after it, so that the outcome is:

```
s = ['acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 116.95.JPG',
     'bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG',
     'bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 002.12.JPG',
     'car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG',
     'car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG']
```

Edit:
The answer provided by Ajax1234 solved my issue:

```
s = sorted(l, key=lambda x:x[:x.index('=')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.index()`:

```
s = [['car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG'],
['bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG'],
['car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG'],
['bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG'],
['acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG']]
new_s = sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[0][:x[0].index('=')])
```

Output:

```
[['acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG'], ['bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG'], ['bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG'], ['car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG'], ['car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG']]
```

Edit: `list.sort()` will also produce the desired output:

```
s.sort()
print(s)
```

Output:

```
[['acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG'], ['bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG'], ['bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG'], ['car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG'], ['car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG']]
```

Regarding your recent comment, this should work:

```
s = ['car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG', 'bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG', 'car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG', 'bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG', 'acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG']
new_s = sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[:x.index('=')])
```

Output:

```
['acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG', 'bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG', 'bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG', 'car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG', 'car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG']
```

Comment: @DOS No problem! Strangely, this code ran fine for me. Did you run the code on `s = [['car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG'],
['bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG'],
['car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG'],
['bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG'],
['acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG']]`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Yes i ran it on that list.Im also afraid i may have made another mistake.I didnt realise that each induvidual  element in the list is not contained by "[]" and only seperated by ",".Sorry im not sure if that has any significance but it is a difference between our solutions.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I think i may have found a fix to the second issue. i used "try" and "except" for the code and it worked.Thank you for your help and sorry for the mixup.

Comment: @DOS Please see my recent edit. I wrote a cleaner solution with the new data.

Comment: @DOS glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To sort a list use list's method `sort()`:

```
l = ['car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG',
     'bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG',
     'car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG',
     'bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG',
     'acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG']

# sort list in place
l.sort()

print('\n'.join(l))
```

will print:

```
acc9=C:/Files/SB.acc9- 006.33.JPG
bike12=C:/Files/SB.bike12- 006.33.JPG
bike53=C:/Files/SB.bike53- 006.33.JPG
car46=C:/Files/SB.car46- 88.22.JPG
car58=C:/Files/SB.car58- 094.38.JPG
```